# Dark theme on Mozilla Firefox won't go away

Tags: firefox, themes

I have Chrome and Firefox on my desktop/laptop and in order to quickly distinguish between which one I am using, I experimented with using a dark theme in Firefox and Chrome. I ended up turning both off, but now on a few web pages when browsing with Firefox the background becomes black and I can't read anything:

[image: Firefox dark theme]

I can't figure out what is causing it, I swear I have turned off all the theme and plugins etc related to the color, anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 2):

From FireFox `about:config` you can set the following setting:

```
browser.display.background_colour
```

Reset it to the original `#ffffff`

Comment: @fixer1234 sorry, that was for a different potential setting, it should be just `#ffffff`. Edited answer